# Create feature class with ArcCatalog in Oracle Spatial without ArcSDE error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, arccatalog, oracle-spatial

I need to create a table/feature class with ArcCatalog 10.2 directly to a Oracle Spatial 11.2 database without ArcSDE, Is it possible? I can execute the create new feature class in ArcCatalog, but after I finish all steps of the wizard (I created a connection to the database with ArcCatalog (Add Database Connection), and clicked right button over that connection -> New -> Feature class) I have the following error: "Failed to create feature class. Undelying DBMS error [ORA-24344]" Could be a database problem? Perhaps something about privileges?

Comment: Please edit the question to contain more details about the exact command you are using to create the table (including the ArcPy tool command before the error message). It appears you are using an ArcSDE connection to create an enterprise geodatabase feature class, but want to do so without an enterprise geodatabase.

Comment: I created a connection to the database with ArcCatalog (Add Database Connection), and clicked right button over that connection -> New -> Feature class. Then I followed the wizard until the end and clicked finished.  I didn´t use any command

Comment: And that is likely the problem (though it really out to be in the question, not hidden here in the comments).

Comment: ORA-24344 is a generic error thrown by the PL/SQL parser when it finds some error in the PL/SQL code it is asked to compile. It looks like your action resulted in some anonymous PL/SQL block (BEGIN ... END) to be generated, and that contains errors. They could be anything, including possibly privilege errors. If you have a way to see that PL/SQL code, then you can just replay it in sqlplus (under the same user as that use by ESRI) and enter the SHOW ERRORS command right after to see the actual errors.

Comment: You should also be able to see the actual PL/SQL compilation errors, but I need to investigate a bit about how that is done.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of misconceptions on what "ArcSDE" is.  I try to always make a clear distinction between "ArcSDE technololgy" (which is the connection protocol and core underpinnings of enterprise geodatabase implementation), an "ArcSDE application server" (the middle tier in the three tier enterprise geodatabase connection protocol), "ArcSDE Direct Connection" (the DLL implementation of the middle tier in a two-tier enterprise geodatabase connection), and "ArcSDE C/Java API" (the software used to maintain a connection and manipulate non-geodatabse spatial objects, which was also used to implement the Esri enterprise geodatabase model as part of ArcObjects).

In this case, you state you don't want to use "ArcSDE", but you've used both an enterprise geodatabase connection protocol (ArcSDE) and the ArcObjects tools that use the ArcSDE 'C' API (ArcSDE) to attempt table creation.  If you *really* don't want to use ArcSDE, you need to be using a DAO or ODBC or JDBC or Python connection to submit SQL in the form of a "`CREATE TABLE`" statement with an `MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY` column.  You can then visualize (but not edit) that table by accessing it through a [Query Layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/00s5/00s500000027000000.htm) (provided that the table validates successfully).  If you want to relax your "no ArcSDE" to "no enterprise geodatabase", then you can use the ability of ArcSDE connections to [submit SQL commands for execution](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/018z/018z0000007z000000.htm), though I prefer to submit DDL SQL from SQL*Plus long before I start Desktop.

Also of note, the only time ArcGIS utilizes "Oracle Spatial" is when a user embeds a Spatial-licensed package in a SELECT expression or WHERE clause (e.g., `SDO_AGGR_CONVEXHULL`).  The low-level SDO_GEOMETRY type is part of the Locator package, which is installed with InterMedia in both standard and enterprise Oracle installs.  Oracle Spatial is an additional cost upgrade to the basic capabilities of the Locator suite (contact your Oracle rep for licensing details).

Comment: Great explanation about ArcSDE. There is still a lot of confusion with all the variants in people's minds (including mine :-) )